# css image overlay on background image

Tags: html, css, image, background-image, overlay

so i am trying to get an overlay to work on my website, i've been watching a tutorial, but now i have gotten to a point where i don't know what i'm doing wrong.

```
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/venues.css">
</head>

<section class="alt-section">

  <h2> Places we've played.</h2>

  <div class="thumb-container">
    <a href ="" class="thumb-unit">
      <div class="thumb-overlay">
        <strong>Bar 42</strong>
        <div class="zoom-icon">
        </div>
      </div>
    </a>

    <a href ="" class="thumb-unit">
      <div class="thumb-overlay">
        <strong>The Prince Albert</strong>
        <div class="zoom-icon">
        </div>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>


</section>
```

and the css is..

```
.alt-section{
  background-color: #e6e6e6;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.alt-section h2{
  padding:50px;
  color: #e1c184;
  font-family: Spliffs;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 35;
}

.alt-section a{
  font-family: sans-serif;
  padding:10px;
  font-size: 18px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #cd9732;
}

.alt-section a:hover{
  color: #e1c184;
}

.thumb-container{
  max-width: 960px;
  margin: 0px auto;
  padding-bottom: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;

}

.thumb-unit{
  display:block;
  width: 150px;
  float:left;
  position: relative;
  height: 150px;



  background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/3VTqQ8M.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
}

.thumb-overlay{
  position:absolute;
  top:100%;
  left:0px;
  right:0px;
  bottom:null;
  height:100%;
  background:rgba(205,151,50,0.5);

}

.thumb-overlay:hover{
  position:absolute;
  top:0%;
  left:0px;
  right:0px;
  bottom:null;
  background:rgba(205,151,50,0.5);
  transition: linear;
  transition-duration: 0.5s;

}
```

The youtube video has got me up to a point where they have completed it but i am still stuck on this. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ygvo1_kqVUg

So my actuall problem is to do with the size of a hitbox on an anchor tag i cant seem to increase the size so when i hover over it the overlay will pop up.

I have turned the overflow back to visible so you can see my problem, but when i scroll over the photo the overlay will not pop up its only when i hover over the writing will it then come up.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
#element-with-background-image {
    background-image:
        linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6)), 
 url("https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/564x/b9/ea/bd/b9eabd96be305e1ee9fe5b6ca3fea673.jpg");
}
 
#color-overlay {
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   background-color: black;
   opacity: 0.6;
```

```html
<div id="element-with-background-image">
  <div id="color-overlay"></div>
   ...
</div>
```